# Fading image inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get it so when the mouse moves over the div it fades the image inside

```
function clickimage($imageid){              
$("#image_"+imageid).hover(function(){
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
},function(){           
$(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
});
}

<div id='images_$imageid'>
<a href='?tg=photos&photo=$imageid' onmouseover=\"javascript:clickimage('$imageid')\">
<img src='users/$ptgid/images/$iimg' width='100' height='100'/>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: so what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set the binding when the document loads, not every time the mouse hovers over the image. Also, I would create a class so that you can initialize the hover on each item

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image-hover-class").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
    },function(){           
        $(this).find('img').fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
    });
});
```

For the link, you would do something like this:

```
<a class="image-hover-class" href="?tg=photos&photo=$imageid" \>
    <img src='users/$ptgid/images/$iimg' width='100' height='100'/>
</a>
```

If you want to do the hover on the `div`, you could do this instead (but I recommend doing the hover on the `<a>` tag):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image-hover-class").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('a img').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
    },function(){           
        $(this).find('a img').fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
    });
});
```

For the div, you would do something like this:

```
<div class="image-hover-class">
    <a href="?tg=photos&photo=$imageid" \>
        <img src='users/$ptgid/images/$iimg' width='100' height='100'/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont see in the image element id attribute.

when you do it

```
$("#image_"+imageid)
```

its try to find this id,
add

id=image_".$imageid." to img

Answer (score 0):

This can be done just using css.  I wrote a tutorial here:

http://www.ozzu.com/html-tutorials/tutorial-creating-hover-effect-elements-using-css-t97597.html

Just include your orignal image and a "faded" image.